# Using component frameworks other than react in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I just started reading about gatsby and it looks really cool!  One caveat: I really dislike writing components in react.  I much prefer riotjs or even polymer.  Is there anyway I could use a different component library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, no, this is not possible.

React is an integral part of how Gatsby works. React forms the link between server side rendering and client side pre-fetching. It's not just the "view layer" that could be easily swapped out for something else.